# Perl to Python - CSV cleaning

Tags: python, perl, csv, data-cleaning

I'm forced to turn from Perl to Python now, took a course even.
But I'm struggling already with a simple data cleaning task on CSV files.
I want to replace a ¶ by a SPACE in a specific column, the other columns must be untouched:

In Perl this is very straight forward and works like a charm:

```
perl -F";" -lane 'BEGIN {$,=";"} print $F[0],$F[1],$F[2],$F[3],$F[4],$F[5],$F[6],$F[7],$F[8],$F[9],$F[10],$F[11], $F[12]=~s/\¶/ /g, $F[13]' a.csv
```

How could I do that in Python? It doesn't need to be a oneliner...

Comment: Do you mind sharing your attempt ?

Comment: Side note; `@F[0..11]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be done in one line (but it would be hard to understand). Here's a slightly more verbose example.

```
import io
import re

with io.open('a.csv') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        parts = line.split(';')
        parts[13] = parts[13].replace('¶', ' ')
        print ','.join(parts)
```

Comment: This would modify all columns. He only wants to modify the 13th.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the csv module for that?

Comment: Excellent point. But I figured he was looking for a lean hack. Sometimes quick & simple beats thorough & complex.

Comment: As long as the OP is ok with columns other than the 13th from time to time, the simple approach is fine.

Comment: Hm, but even with a CSV-Module, you have to define the delimiter, so that wouldn't help either, would it?